# Why was Hitler friendly toward Arabs given that they are Semitic too?

Tags: hitler

Anti Semites hate Jews. However, I found it strange that they call their hatred anti semitism. Didn't they know that arabs are semites too?

Hitler seem to think that some race were destroying civilization (many would disagree, but that was his opinion). One such race is the Jews. Some say that Hitler hated Jews even more than blacks.

Hitler thought that blacks are civilization "helping" while Jews or Semites are civilization destroying. Or so I heard.

Yet Hitler was friendly toward Arab that are Semites too.

Why?

Some would say that semites in hitler eyes **only means** jews. I found this **a bit strange**. I mean the whole german didn't know that Arab are semites too? What?

Obviously racism, like any ideology and religion, is ridiculous in general. However, they must have some sort of explanation to justify this ridiculousness.

Comment: Because "anti-Semitism" is a scientific-sounding term for Jew-hatred, and has nothing to do with the Semites.

Comment: yes to @congusbongus and you might want reserch and describe how exactly this 'friendlyness' looked like to further improve the question.

Comment: Why an individual felt hatred towards a group is a question for psychology, not history.  Hitler was deranged; his belief were inconsistent, incoherent, hypocritical and wrong.  It is difficult to "descriptively and objectively" understand incoherent demagoguery.

Comment: Why Hitler liked or didn't some race is psychology. Why Nazi ideology was for or against some thing is politics. Whether or not the Nazi regime during WWII was for or against some thing _during WWII_ might be historical. Perhaps you might work on the wording of your question?

Comment: It's slightly ambiguous but I feel that the question is primarily about the historical distinction between Jewish/Arabic/Semitic within the context of Nazi Germany in the late 1930s and early 1940s

Comment: Why the downvote? Look pal I am not even white or aryan. I am just confused with what happen in europe at that time. I do NOT hate jews.

Comment: The reason why I am curious is because of similarity between what happened to jews and what used to happened to chinese. Hindsight is 20 20 and I want to learn.

Comment: Hitler hating blacks is a common misconception. He never said he hated blacks. Rather that he wishes every race on earth would follow the same nationalistic ideas. A big reason for the jewish hate in Germany was the civil war after world war one, which was started by jews.

Comment: I would also like to know why there are so many downvotes on this question. I was searching for the same thing on google and found this answer.

Comment: @congusbongus Who says?

Comment: Nazi ideas on race were flexible, disorganised and of necessity pragmatic. As part of some business I was doing in the 1970s, I met a former SS officer who had been a Soviet POW for about ten years. When I explained that I had previously worked in Japan - he responded with "Ah - good people the Japanese - we used to call them the Germans of the east. The Turks we called the Germans of the near-east, the Japanese, the German of the far east". I didn't bother to ask him what they had called the Italians - but I doubt, somehow, it was "the Germans of the south".

Comment: Jews start civil war after world war one? What?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although arabs are official "semites" historically, "Anti-semitic" is really meant in this context as "anti-Jewish".

That's slightly confusing, I know, but Hitler didn't dislike the historical semite people for a "the semitic people did *xyz* bad thing"... he "only" hated the Jews because he blamed them specifically for various problems in Germany at the time.

It's equivalent to if I today chose to hate Germany because I think their flag is silly: that doesn't necessarily mean I hate Germanic people (including Austrians, who's flag I like)... it's a semantic difference. You might then say I was anti-Germanic, which sounds correct but isn't really. I'm anti-Germany, not anti-Germanic

This is different from me saying "the historical Germanic people invaded my country and said mean things about my mother, so I hate both Germans, Austrians and anyone else descended from a Germanic tribe" in which case it would be true to say that I am anti-Germanic.

In short, we should really say Hitler was **anti-Jewish** not **anti-Semitic**: but in recent years "Semite" and "Semitic" have been primarily used to refer to the Jewish people, rather than all Semite-descended peoples.

Comment: You mean the whole german didn't know that arab are semites too? They honestly think that semites only mean jews? Seriously? I mean what's their explanation?

Comment: That's my point: by the 1930s Jews and Arabs were different enough that it stopped making sense to call them both Semites. The meaning of Semite had changed and no longer really refers to Arabs unless talking strictly historically

Answer (score 4):

When the word "antisemitism" was first coined, it was a characterisation of a French linguist in the 19th century named Ernst Renan, who believed that Semitic peoples were inferior. "Semitic" was, of course, a language family; Semitic peoples were the peoples who spoke languages within that family. Such languages include Hebrew (which belongs to the Canaanite branch of this family), Aramaic, Phoenician, Arabic and Akkadian (amongst others). Renan believed that Jesus was a descendant of Sumerians, whose ancestors had been moved to the land of Israel by the Assyrians, and *not* like the Semitic peoples amongst whom he lived.

As you can tell, it's but a short step from there to the sort of race-motivated doctrines of the later 19th century, and by the time that the word "antisemitism" became popularised (by Wilhelm Marr, specifically, at the close of the century) it was synonymous with a hatred of Jews in particular.

As to why Hitler developed alliances with non-Aryan peoples, suffice it to say that he was a pragmatist as well as an ideologue. He granted the Japanese "honorary Aryan" status, for example, which is plainly absurd if being an Aryan is in some sense biologically determined. (It isn't, for the record; race itself is a social construct.)

Within this Nazi racial hierarchy, Jews inhabited the lowest rung - almost like a master race of their own, but placed diametrically opposite all that was good and healthy in the world. The fact that the word "antisemitic" originally denoted a dislike of all Semitic peoples was irrelevant - as was the fact that the word "Semitic" originally denoted speakers of particular languages. By the time that the Nazis ruled Germany, "antisemitism" had taken on a new meaning, and friendship with other Semitic peoples was no obstruction to it.

Answer (score 2):

The use of “Semite” in Germany goes back to the 1860s and is a bit convoluted.  During this period it developed that the Christian church was considered by some to be a Jewish sect, i.e. Jew being generic and Christian a species thereof.  Since there were few Semites in Germany other than Jews, Jews were identified as Semites to distinguish them from nonSemite Christian (species) Jews (genus).

Outside of provincial Germany, this makes no sense.  All descendants of Sem (Shem) were Semites.

This is submitted as an “answer” in that I don’t have standing to comment’

Comment: Can you supply any evidence for the sentence which reads "During this period [the 1860s] it developed that the Christian church was considered by some to be a Jewish sect"? Since the vast majority of Germans in the 19th century were either Lutheran or Roman Catholic I am wondering who the "some people" were who regarded the Christian churches as "Jewish sects". There is a vast and well-documented history of relations between Jews and the Papacy from the early middle-ages to modern times. I am just wondering where this idea of Christians being regarded as sects of Judaism fits with that?